Custom strapi plugin deployment strapi cloud
I am developing my second strapi project and want to host it using strapi cloud. In my project I have create a plugin (to extend the features of CMS). In the development everything is fine and in my own hosting also, because I am able to use my own commands (build plugin first, then strapi).
In strapi cloud not, has someone experiences with this scenario? In the documentation of strapi it is written, that strapi checks for plugins, but when I call strapi build it mentions that the dist folder is missing and I don't want to commit the dist folder.

Found it and it is quit simple. Just to let you know:
Add all your commands needed an a command called "prebuild" in the scripts section of the package.json of the strapi installation. It it the one in the root folder of strapi not the one for the plugin.
